# mongoose doesn't work during a find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema:

```
var mySchema = Schema({
    categories: {
            newPr: Boolean;
            elitePr: Boolean;
            check: Boolean
}
});
```

create a object:

```
 var one = new mySchema({newPr: true})
 var two = new mySchema({elitePr: true, newPr: true})
```

when I use :

```
mySchema.find({categories: {newPr: true}}, cb)
```

**it returns ONLY 'one' , but it should return ['one', 'two'].
What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: does 'two' exists in the mongodb collections ?? check in  shell query

Comment: In the `two`, the `newPr: true` exists too, so it will return...

Comment: 'one', 'two' in collections.

Comment: exmaple :
schema({ age: number, title: string})
One = new schema({age: 20, title: 'Pavel'})
Two = new schema({age: 20, title: 'Sania'})

Schema.find({age: 20}, callback) // return One, Two

Why my first example dosn't return 'one', 'two'.

Comment: 'two' - don't return